# Correct "As" Clause to use

Tags: arrays, vb.net, find, controls

I'm using VB.net and trying to fully define a variable `FoundComboBoxes` but when I use `As` I get errors.

I've tried `Control` which errored as expected, `Control()`, `Control.ControlCollection` and too many others to remember. It runs if I omit the `As` clause.

Hovering on `Find` says it returns "An array of type Control containing the matching controls."

```
Dim FoundComboBoxes As Control() = parentCtrls.Parent.Parent.Parent.Controls.Find(ThisCtrl.Name.Replace("Reqd", ""), True).OfType(Of ComboBox)
```

Here is the error:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type
> 'd__65`1[System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox]' to type
> 'System.Array'.'

Questions:

1. What do I use for the `As` clause?
2. Is there a better way to write this chunk of code to find controls that have names starting with a certain string?
3. Maybe a low altitude explainer for me and others.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Find() returns a type of collection, but `.OfType(Of ComboBox)()` retruns another. Set `Option Infer ON` if it's not, declare `Dim FoundComboBoxes = parentCtrls. [...]` and inspect what type `FoundComboBoxes` is now (LINQ methods return IEnumerable) -- BTW, that `Parent.Parent.Parent` thing needs serious refactoring

Comment: Also look better at the exception message. It is not exactly as you have typed. There is a clear reference to the _OfTypeIterator_ pointing to the exact problem stated above by @jimi

Comment: Agreed @Jimi. The `Parent.Parent.Parent` thig was really the reason for question 2. I'm sure you can tell I'm a greenie. :)

Comment: The error is stating that you are trying to assign a scalar `ComboBox` to an array of `Control`.  You can't do that.  If you want to assign to an array, you need to start with an array.  You may be able to do that using `ToArray()` if you have a sequence (this is what I would expect to get from `OfType(Of T)` but it would also give a slightly different error from what you've posted) or by wrapping the entire expression in braces to make it into an array.

Comment: @Jimi, I tried a top down Find `Dim FoundComboBoxes As Array = ECR_ECO_Details.Controls.Find(ThisCtrl.Name.Replace("Inform", ""), True).OfType(Of ComboBox).ToArray()`. Using a `For Each` loop 1Debug.Print("FoundComboBox.Name = " & FoundComboBox.Name)` works and shows the name but `FoundComboBox.Enabled = True` has no effect. The ugly up-and-over `Parent.Parent.Parent way works though.

Comment: When you think you need to find a Control by name, there's something (quite) wrong with the design. You can, e.g., a) build a model (a class) that binds a Control to another b) build a UserControl which contains the Controls that need to *cooperate* c) use (as in your case) a `Dictionary(Of CheckBox, ComboBox)`: when the CheckBox is interacted with, you get the associated ComboBox from the Dictionary. E.g., in the `CheckedChanged` event handler, `[The Dictionary](CType(sender, CheckBox)).Enabled = true`

Comment: When you inspect a Dictionary by `Key` - the CheckBox instance in this case - it returns the related `Value`, which is the associated ComboBox in this example -- You should (really) specify what `parentCtrls` and  `ThisCtrl` are and where / when is the code that you have posted called. Missing crucial details and context may prevent a *sensible* answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to answer your requirement, rather than answer your exact question.

Since each control can contain other controls, you need to iterate over each control's contents. A lot of the base WinForms classes predate LINQ and therefore don't fully support it. I don't think this is easily a one-liner.

You can either use a recursive or stack-based solution.

I've coded up a recursive solution, below.

```
Public Class Form1
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim controlsArray(Me.Controls.Count - 1) As Control
    Me.Controls.CopyTo(controlsArray, 0)
    Dim taggedControls = FindControlsByName(controlsArray, "tagged", GetType(ComboBox))
    For Each taggedControl In taggedControls
      ListBox1.Items.Add(taggedControl.Name)
    Next
  End Sub


  Function FindControlsByName(controls As Control(), expression As String, controlType As Type) As Control()
    Dim output(-1) As Control
    For Each currentControl As Control In controls
      If currentControl.Controls.Count > 0 Then
        Dim containedControlsArray(currentControl.Controls.Count - 1) As Control
        currentControl.Controls.CopyTo(containedControlsArray, 0)
        Dim containedControls = FindControlsByName(containedControlsArray, expression, controlType) 'Recursive call
        ReDim Preserve output(output.Length + containedControls.Length - 1)
        For i = 0 To containedControls.Length - 1
          output(output.Length - 1 - i) = containedControls(i)
        Next i
      End If
      If currentControl.Name.StartsWith(expression) Then 'decide if control name matches criteria
        ReDim Preserve output(output.Length)
        output(output.Length - 1) = currentControl
      End If
    Next currentControl
    Return output
  End Function

End Class
```

Comment: P.S. If "Reqd" means "Required" and you are trying to ensure the user is entering values for mandatory fields, I'd recommend you do this at the ViewModel level rather than on the UI level.

Comment: Reqd and Inform are the ending of CheckBox names and does not mean it is mandatory for the user check. It refers to physical, real-world tasks to be performed by certain individual users if a CheckBox is checked. I.E. if someone is required to inspect and approve paperwork -or- if they are merely to be informed that paperwork exists and they should probably review it.

Answer (score 0):

`Dim FoundComboBoxes As Array = parentCtrls.TopLevelControl.Controls.Find(ThisCtrl.Name.Replace("Reqd", ""), True).OfType(Of ComboBox).ToArray()`

`Dim FoundComboBoxes As Array = parentCtrls.TopLevelControl.Controls.Find(ThisCtrl.Name.Replace("Inform", ""), True).OfType(Of ComboBox).ToArray()`

This gathers exactly what I need, filters out anything other than ComboBoxes, and no longer has the ugly `Parent.Parent.Parent` thing. I added `.ToArray()` to the end as @Craig suggested and the error no longer occurs.

Going from the top down (absolute) rather than up-and-over (relative) cleans up the ugly `Parent.Parent.Parent` thing and makes it more readable, concise and much shorter. I used `TopLevelControl` rather than the form name because this `Sub` is used by more than one form.

Iterating is undoubtedly the more robust way of gathering controls if they were scattered unpredictably about the form.

Checkbox names are, for example: QualityManagerReqd or QualityManagerInform, ProductionManagerReqd or ProductionManagerInform, EngManagerGroupLeadReqd or EngManagerGroupLeadInform

Used to find ComboBox (populated with people's names) named: QualityManager,
ProductionManager or EngManagerGroupLead